# IIS Headers appearing at regular intervals in Log Files

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

From my IIS logs, I could see that on a random basis IIS log header inserted into my logs, Which causes me a little time delay processing client request on the particular second.
The log is something like,

```
2019-01-21 20:59:41 10.45.122.15 POST /api/push/xml X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&SERVER-ROUTED=VRN-SRV-ATT901&X-ARR-LOG-ID=9da86764-278b-46b3-becb-f03a58f001c7&SERVER-STATUS=200 7085 - 10.45.120.123 AHC/1.0 - 200 0 0 31

    #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
    #Version: 1.0
    #Date: 2019-01-21 21:00:01
    #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2019-01-21 21:00:01 10.45.122.15 POST /api/push/xml X-ARR-CACHE-HIT=0&SERVER-ROUTED=VRN-SRV-ATT902&X-ARR-LOG-ID=64631efc-b15a-4ff9-a817-bf6c2bc18118&SERVER-
```

I know that the IIS header is automatically added by IIS at the start of the log file and also there is a 15 minute period of inactivity.

In the case I am asking about, this happened in the middle of the server handling a request from the user, but in general on this server there is on a daily basis at 11:00:00 GMT, 15:00:00 GMT, 26:00:00 and 23:00:00 GMT  each day the header is inserted into the middle of the log file.

Comment: Is the application pool that hosts your app set to restart after either a fixed number of minutes, or at fixed times (i.e. 11:00, 15:00, etc,..) as these are possible causes of this

Comment: No, The Regular time intervals and Specific times in Recycling are not set.

Comment: @Rob any update on the comment